# Color differences between threejs + vanilla js and react-three-fiber + create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

This has been bugging me for a while. Why the material colors in react-three-fiber appears to be dull than in threejs

- Objects and their properties are same in both implementations.
- threejs version is same.
- Implemented in freshly bootstraped
  create-react-app with no additional dependencies.

**Threejs**

[image]

**react-three-fiber**

[image]

Comment: It looks like react-three-fiber probably has tone mapping enabled by default, which shifts colors a bit. You could enable that in three.js with the `renderer.toneMapping` setting, but I don't know what setting is used to disable it in react-three-fiber...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

r3f uses correct gamma in a srgb colorspace and automatically converts colors and textures to srgb. this is similar to what aframe does. threejs has incorrect gamma settings in a linear colorspace, which is not very usable. wrong gamma is the #1 reason for cheap, plasticy looking 3d scenes. see: https://www.donmccurdy.com/2020/06/17/color-management-in-threejs

if you want a linear colorspace, just do: `<Canvas colorManagement={false}>` and now your colors will match.

Comment: Getting ``React does not recognize the `colorManagement` prop on a DOM element.`` using ``react-three-fiber ^8.0.0``

Answer (score 9):

As answered by [Don McCurdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314762/don-mccurdy), setting renderer toneMapping to default one does help.

```
<Canvas onCreated={({ gl }) => { gl.toneMapping = THREE.NoToneMapping }}>
```

Answer (score 6):

The following combination gave me the best match to my colors in threejs.

```
  <Canvas
    gl={{ antialias: true, toneMapping: THREE.NoToneMapping }}
    linear
  >
```

Thank you Don and devAhsan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the updated version to do it is to pass a flat prop to your React Three Fiber canvas

```
<Canvas flat>
   ...
</Canvas>
```