# Color Diffferance in React-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

In React three fiber when using both `meshBasicMaterial` and when using `meshStandardMaterial` in the component used to render a box with an image texture, the texture looks different than the original image. I have tried putting `colorManagement={false}` in the canvas component, but nothing changed. Thanks in advance.

In React Three Fiber

[image: In React Three Fiber]

Original Images Used
[image: Original React Logo]

[image: Original Js Logo]

Code Used

```js
function Element( props ) {
const ref = useRef()
props = props.props
useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01))
const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, props.texture)
return (
    <mesh
    ref={ref}
    position={props.position}
    rotation={[0,0,-10]}
    >
        <boxGeometry args={[1,0,1]}/>
        <meshBasicMaterial map={texture} texture={'sRGB'} transparent={true} />
    </mesh >
)

}


const CameraControls = () => {
const {
    camera,
    gl: { domElement },
} = useThree();
// Ref to the controls, so that we can update them on every frame using useFrame
const controls = useRef();
useFrame((state) => controls.current.update());
return <orbitControls ref={controls} args={[camera, domElement]} />;
};

export default function App() {
return (
    <>
        <div style={{
            height: '100vh',
            width: '100vw',
        }}>
            <Canvas>
                <CameraControls />
                <ambientLight color={ '#ffffff' } intensity={.5}/>
                <group>
                    <Element props={{texture: 'react.png', position: [1,1,0]}}/>
                    <Element props={{texture: 'js.png', position: [3,3,-2]}}/>
                </group>


            </Canvas>
        </div>
    </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as seen in [Color differences between threejs + vanilla js and react-three-fiber + create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899716/color-differences-between-threejs-vanilla-js-and-react-three-fiber-create-re) This worked although not the answer on that thread it worked better than what was chosen as the answer. `<Canvas gl={{ antialias: true, toneMapping: NoToneMapping }} linear>`

Comment: I think the updated version to do it is to pass a flat prop to your React Three Fiber canvas

<Canvas flat>
   ...
</Canvas>